# Calculate RTT with 3 decimal places in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, rounding, decimal-point

I have a simple UDP client–server program and I get the time in ms of sending a packet and the time in ms of receiving the packet like this:

```
send_time_ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
# sending the packet
# ...
# receiving the packet
recv_time_ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

For example, I get `1430645866889` and `1430645866898`. I would like to then find the difference between these two values and round it to a value with 3 decimal places, like `0.291` and so on. I tried subtracting them, but it gave me 9 or 10.0 in float. I must be doing this wrong.

Could you please help me find a way to edit the `time.time()` code so I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second argument of `round` which indicates the number of numbers after the decimal:

```
send_time_ms = time.time()
...
recv_time_ms = time.time()
rtt_in_ms = round(recv_time_ms - send_time_ms, 3)
```